# What is causing `diff` to run `git diff`?

Tags: osx, zsh, alias, diff, prezto

I'd like to use `diff` as described [here](http://lifehacker.com/compare-the-contents-of-two-folders-with-the-diff-comma-598872057) and in the documentation I see when I type `man diff`. However, when I type `diff`, what I get is this:

```
~ ❯❯❯ diff
usage: git diff --no-index <path> <path>
```

Similarly when I try to *use* `diff`, I get git errors because `-rq` is supported in `man diff` but not by `git diff`:

```
~ ❯❯❯ diff -rq ~/ ~/Desktop
fatal: invalid diff option/value: -rq
```

I'm using [Prezto](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto) and [hub](https://github.com/github/hub) which both help with git productivity, but neither creates an alias that doesn't at *least* start with `g`, as far as I can tell.

I've run a few scripts like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176205/how-to-find-file-defining-an-alias) to try to find something that's defining `diff` to `git diff` but to no avail.

How do I fix this/find what's causing it/override it?

## Edit

Ran `type diff`:

```
diff is a shell function
diff is /usr/bin/diff
```

Comment: Run `type diff` and post the output.

Comment: And I suspect it will be https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto/blob/master/modules/utility/functions/diff

Comment: @MichaelHomer Added. That does look right to me.

Comment: I don't know how you tell prezto not to do that, but worst case you can just hack it out.

Comment: Yep. Do you want to submit an answer? Because that's the answer. I think I'll just use `command diff` which seems to run `diff` for now. Maybe try to figure out a better strategy later.

Comment: IN FACT! I ran `brew install colordiff` and now `diff` runs `colordiff`, which is an actual `diff`-based thing.

Comment: I'd stay away from the work of someone who thinks nothing of calling a shell function `diff`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems to be from [prezto defining a function overriding `diff`](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto/blob/master/modules/utility/functions/diff). It may well have a way of disabling that, but I don't know what it is ([but ericbn does!](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/302550/73093)). You have a few options:

- `/usr/bin/diff` or `command diff` will both run the `diff` command, rather than the function.
- `unset -f diff` will remove the `diff` function. You could put that in your shell configuration.
- As you've found, if `colordiff` is installed it will be used in preference to `git diff` by the function.
- Finally, you can remove or rename the function from that file itself.

This really seems like a misfeature in prezto.

Comment: certainly a good example of the ills of global scope and naming collisions

Answer (score 2):

I would use an function like this

```
$ diffit () {
command diff "$@"
}
```

A function over an alias as there are parameters

Usage: `diffit file1 file2`

You could put it in your .bashrc
Personally I keep my collection of functions in `.bash_functions` and in `.bashrc` I have

```
test -f ~/.bash_functions.sh && . $_
```

Comment: Just make it `command diff "$@"`.

Answer (score 1):

As @MichaelHomer answered, this is a prezto function, part of the utility module documented in https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto/tree/master/modules/utility. The way to disable this is:

> To disable diff highlighting, add the following line to zpreztorc:
>
> ```
> zstyle ':prezto:module:utility:diff' color 'no'
> ```

Or installing `colordiff` would also make the custom function call it instead of `git diff`, as the purpose of the custom prezto `diff` is:

> - `diff` highlights diff output (requires `colordiff` or `Git`).